# Angular Get a ramdom key from json

Tags: json, angular, api

I would like to know how I can get a value of a key by the name inside of the object.

Example: I pass the name of title "Black" and they return the pk value "**170238**" inside of json object

**api.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ApiService {
  private readonly API_URL = "xxx";
  private readonly header_job = { Authorization: "Token" };
  private parData: any = { ref_number: "4806" };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  jobStates(ref_number: string) {
    this.parData = { ref_number };
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/combo/jobs/jobstates/?ref_number=${ref_number}`, {
      headers: { ...this.header_job },
    });
  }
```

**Result of API**

```
[
    {
        "order": 0,
        "title": "Brown",
        "pk": 170231
    },
    {
        "order": 1,
        "title": "Black",
        "pk": 170238
    },
    {
        "order": 2,
        "title": "White",
        "pk": 170239
    },
    {
        "order": 3,
        "title": "Blue",
        "pk": 170240
    },
    {
        "order": 4,
        "title": "Red",
        "pk": 170241
    },
    {
        "order": 5,
        "title": "Yellow",
        "pk": 170242
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.find()` function to get the data you need

```
this.apiService.jobStates(ref_number).subscribe(response => {
   const job_ref = response.find(r => r.title === title);
   if (job_ref !== undefined) {
      // set variable with job_ref.pk
   }
});
```

I don't know how you specifically want to set your data, so I used an Observable implementation.

```
myFunction() {
    getPkValueByTitle(this.ref_number, this.title).subscribe(pk => {
        // set variable with pk
    });
}

getPkValueByTitle(ref_number, title: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
        this.apiService.jobStates(ref_number).subscribe(response => {
            const job_ref = response.find(r => r.title === title);
            if (job_ref !== undefined) {
                observer.next(job_ref.pk);
            } else {
                observer.next(null);
            }
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: or you can use the `.filter()` function to return only what you need. note that this is untested code so it may need some tweaking

```
  jobStates(ref_number: string, title: string) {
    this.parData = { ref_number };
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/combo/jobs/jobstates/?ref_number=${ref_number}`, {
      headers: { ...this.header_job },
    }).filter(value => value.title === title);
  }
```

Comment: I get error on Property  'find' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Comment: @ialexsilva did you get it to work? find should work on an array which is what you provided as your api result.

Comment: yes, works i declared the find property on es5